# Is my Raphael "text-overflow: ellipsis;" implementation plugin an overkill?

Tags: javascript, plugins, raphael, css

I needed to use a `text-overflow: ellipsis;` CSS declaration in Raphael text elements, but couldn't find an existing cross-browser solution (perhaps my search skills failed me?).

So I created my own Raphael plugin `fitText` that does exactly what I want. It fits text to a certain width. It's not perfect, but it works. Here's a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sCEBD/1/)** and a **[github page](https://github.com/olegskl/fitText)**.

Now I'm thinking...

1. Is my solution an overkill? In other word, do easier ways exist to tackle the problem?
2. Is it worth the effort continuing to work on the plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

certainly not an overkill, as the `text-overflow: ellipsis` is not widely supported yet, and won't be for non-modern browsers. i've encountered this very issue myself, and tackled it with a similar approach.

regardless, after looking at the source, several suggestions:

- you may want to improve performance by caching heavy calls to `getBBox()`
- API design: i think passing arguments (`text`, `width`) is redundant, as this information can be retrieved from the element itself. the API end-user will probably want to just call `fillText()` on an element and forget about it.

Comment: Appreciate your suggestions. I left a comment on github regarding getBBox. The `text` argument should remain for update reasons, but I will make `width` default to paper size... totally forgot about it. Thanks.

Comment: perhaps a better choice on the `width` is to have default to the text parent shape's width.

Comment: Do nested structures exist in Raphael? I'm probably misunderstanding something, but I thought it's just paper and elements on it.

Comment: i wasn't very clear - one could pass a shape ('parent') as an argument to determine the width accordingly.

Comment: Could be interesting. I'll think about that.

Comment: Super! Very usefull plugin! Thank you for your contribution!